# Python - Releasing/replacing a string variable, how does it get handled?

Tags: python, memory-management

Say i store a password in plain text in a variable called `passWd` as a string.
How does python release this variable once i discard of it (for instance, with `del passWd` or `passWd= 'new random data'`)?

Is the string stored as a byte-array meaning it can be overwritten in the memoryplace that it originally existed or is it a fixed set in a memory area which can't be modified and there for when assining a new value a new memory area is created and the old area is discareded but not overwritten by null?

I'm questioning how Python implements the safety of memory areas and would like to know more about it, mainly because i'm curious :)

From what i've gathered so far, using `del` (or `__del__`) causes the interpreter to not release memory areas of that variable automaticly which can cause issues, and also i'm not sure that **del** is so thurrow on deleting the values. But that's just from what i've gathered and not something in black or white :)

Comment: While many people may know the answer here on SU, this should be posted on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), I assume it'll be migrated soon.

Comment: I didn't dare to ask on SO, since my question isn't "i need help with this code problem" it's more of, "how is the memory management implemented on lower levels" :) but i guess i can give SO a chance to not hate on me :P

Comment: Just a suggestion for posting over there: use a valid identifier since `pass` is a keyword in Python and couldn't be used :)  Most people over there are pretty reasonable.

Comment: A good and a valid point! Thank you! :) Also, you are very reasonable!

Comment: Next time please don't cross post. As @nerdwaller said, your question could have been migrated.

Comment: @slhck i'm aware but i made a conscious choice to not wait for that to happen in this specific case because i was in a great hurry. So i'd rather take -1 hit just this once to get help as soon as possible. Again, i know it's not the routine so i apolegize but hope that you can view it from my paniced viewpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is implementation specific. from http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

under 5.6 Sequence Types, take note of "Notes #6" which explains that some implementations (CPython for one) do in-place string updates in memory, whereas others presumably treat the string as a immutable object, that when replaced/altered defines a new area in memory.

Comment: I was hoping that was the case, otherwise i would have needed to write some C code of my own to actually do that job, if python didn't have a workaround for it that is.
Assuming Py2.6+ there are some neat stuff like in-place concationations occur which is great.. But how about deletions, are they handled in a way that the momory is actually cleared, replaced by null or is it a standard `free()` on a `malloc` allocation? According to StackOverflow it's just freed, making it a security risk and i would have to do `passWd = '...'` before freeing the memory area, and even then, can i be sure?

Comment: python is an intrepreter langague and uses garbage collection as the default memory recovery mechanism. per http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html objects that do not define __del__() are garbage collected, whereas objects that do are not collectable and appear in the gc.Garbage return and must be released manually. running gc.collect() will cause the system to try to start disposing unlinked objects in memory, but garbage collection is never an explicit thing, but a best effort attempt.